# jHipster 8: Can I use jhipster microservices with session based authentication. I want one login per user across ip and sessions

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, jhipster-gateway

Does this jdl work?. I am using authenticationType session in gateway as well as microservices.

```
application {
  config {
    enableTranslation true
    applicationType gateway
    serviceDiscoveryType consul
    languages [en, hi, te]
    nativeLanguage en
    packageName in.beze.pc
    testFrameworks [gatling, cucumber, protractor]
    websocket spring-websocket
    baseName pc
    serverPort 8080
    jhiPrefix sys
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    devDatabaseType postgresql
    databaseType sql
    cacheProvider ehcache
    enableHibernateCache true
    authenticationType session
    buildTool gradle
    clientPackageManager npm
    clientFramework angularX
  }
  entities *
}

application {
  config {
    baseName masters
    applicationType microservice
    packageName in.beze.masters
    serviceDiscoveryType consul
    authenticationType session
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    devDatabaseType postgresql
    databaseType sql
    buildTool gradle
    serverPort 8081
    skipUserManagement true
    cacheProvider ehcache
    enableHibernateCache true
    websocket spring-websocket
  }
  entities Attachment, ContentType, Equipment, EquipmentType, FacilityType, FacilityGroupType, FacilityGroup, Facility, FacilityHistory, FacilityUser, FacilityAttachment, FacilityEquipment, FrequencyType, Frequency, Gender, JobSandbox, Language, Party, Permission, PermissionAuthority, ProductStoreType, ProductStore, ProductStoreFacility, ProductStoreUserGroup, Responsibility, RoleType, Scheduler, StatusCategory, Status, StatusValidChange, UserRole, UserGroup, UserGroupAuthority, UserGroupMember, Uom, UomType, UserAttachment, SystemParameters, QRCode, QRCodeType, QRCodeAttachment, Product, ProductType, ProductCategoryType, ProductCategory, ProductCategoryMember, Stage, ProductSpecGroup, ProductSpec, ProductSpecItem, StabilityCondition, StabilityConditionAttachment
}
```

application {
config {
baseName stability
applicationType microservice
packageName in.beze.stability
serviceDiscoveryType consul
authenticationType jwt
prodDatabaseType postgresql
devDatabaseType postgresql
databaseType sql
buildTool gradle
serverPort 8082
skipUserManagement true
cacheProvider ehcache
enableHibernateCache true
websocket spring-websocket
}
entities StAttachment, StContentType, AnalysisType, SpEquipment, SsEquipment, SpProductSpec, StabilityProgramme, StabilityAttachment, SampleType, StabilitySample, SampleResult, SampleAttachment, SampleResultAttachment, EquipmentSc
}

Note that I am using Session in all microservices and gateway. Is it the correct way to generate microservices with one login per user.

Answer (score 0):

No. JHipster doesn't support session-based authentication for microservices. Only JWT and OAuth are supported for microservices because of their distributed nature.

What are you hoping to accomplish with session-based authentication?

Comment: I need to restrict application to One login allowed per session, and a maximum of one concurrent login. I thought with session based we have better control with sessions and IP.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, with session-based or any other type of authentication.